# Isabelle: Why do I get completely different results when running try versus sledgehammer

Tags: isabelle

When I look only (this is not stated in the title)
at the Sledgehammer results, the output of 
try often gives various results from sledgehammer
while running sledgehammer directly gives zero(!) results.

Now I know, the design goal of Sledgehammer was not determinism,
[as stated by Lawrence Paulson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076190/isabelle-getting-three-different-results-with-sledgehammer-for-what-seems-to-be).
However, this seemingly random results without understanding why
are a bit discouraging for beginners,
not only for me but also for students helping in projects.

A possibility would be to always run Sledgehammer and try in parallel.

I don't need an exact answer, but does anybody have a clue why the results could be different? Are the two sledgehammer calls featuring different parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would recommend subscribing to the Isabelle user's mailing list to watch for information about these things. In particular, in the last six months, there were threads about Sledgehammer

- how `sledgehammer` is related to `try`,
- how the `Auto methods` in `Isabelle / Options` is related to `try`,
- how multi-threading affects `try` and `sledgehammer`,
- how options and provers are set for the Sledgehammer panel which can be used to run `sledgehammer,
- how the number of CPU cores affect how the options are automatically set for `sledgehammer`,
- and generally how provers are chosen for Sledgehammer in various ways, some automatic.

That's all related to your question, where one short answer to your questions is that two big things that affect `sledgehammer` output are the options and multi-threading, where you can only completely control the `sledgehammer` options by giving it options when you use it, or by setting the options using `sledgehammer-params`.

Below, I give some links to the mailing list, where M.Wenzel gave a short explanation about Sledgehammer's automatic settings yesterday.

Another answer to your second question is this: The `try` command is a multi-threaded combination of `try0` and `sledgehammer`. There are the default `sledgehammer` options, which can be viewed with `sledgehammer_param`. If you haven't changed these options, then the command `sledgehammer`, when used in your theory, will use these options. Whether `try` is using these options, I don't know, but I'll show you how to determine whether `try` is giving `sledgehammer` a prover that's not listed in the default options.

I assume that `try` works for you like it works for me.

First, insert `sledgehammer_params` and look at the output panel. It will show you the `provers`. My default is `e spass vampire z3`, because I have 4 cores. These were chosen on startup by the PIDE. These are the same provers that will be shown in the Sledgehammer panel. A second important options will be `timeout = 30`.

When I insert `try` for a theorem which `try0` methods can't prove, and which `sledgehammer` can, along with each `by` proof that's listed in the output panel, it will tell me the ATP (automatic theorem prover) which found the proof. For example, mine shows me `"e"`, `"z3"`, and `"spass"`, each followed by a proof.

**Answer:** If `try` shows an ATP that's not listed when you use `sledgehammer_params`, then `try` is giving `sledgehammer` a different `provers` option than when you run `sledgehammer` with the default options.

**Running a prover that try listed:** To answer your question about whether you can get `sledgehammer` to give you the same `sledgehammer` proof that `try` gives you, run the individual provers that `try` listed, for example like this:

```
sledgehammer[provers = "z3", timeout = 60]
```

I show `timeout` just to show that you can change it, but you generally wouldn't need a longer timeout because `try` doesn't try things forever.

If your explicit use of `sledgehammer` gives you a `z3` proof, when `try` has given you a `z3` proof, then this tells you that it's the options and multi-threading that affect the different outcomes. I definitely know that the output of `sledgehammer` and `nitpick` vary greatly.

I don't use `try`. I use `try0` and `sledgehammer`, but what you say shows that the automatically set options for the auto methods are better. Auto `nitpick` finds counterexamples that `nitpick` doesn't find because I've changed the options for `nitpick`.

**Links**

- [Re: [isabelle] Two configuration questions](http://lists.cam.ac.uk/mailman/htdig/cl-isabelle-users/2014-February/msg00067.html)
- [[isabelle] Isabelle2013-1-RC3: try no longer seems to give preference to try0 over sledgehammer](http://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/fa.isabelle/try$20sledgehammer/fa.isabelle/dWHc0ivkeco/a2ZfLnK3vWAJ)
- [[isabelle] Auto sledgehammer fails to find proofs sledgehammer finds.](http://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/fa.isabelle/try$20sledgehammer/fa.isabelle/rvbCEw2Ld8s/tJ0JwpWWnakJ)